# Where can I find replacement door knobs?

Tags: doors

In the apartment that I am renting, the bedroom door knob does not have a lock on it.  I am looking to replace the door knob with one that has one.  However, the door seems to have a knob mounting that I am unfamiliar with.  The locks that I've changed in the past have the screws inside the lock, and it seems that this one has them outside of the main hole.  It also seems like a larger handle. Is this a larger lock then normal?  What is a cheaper type replacement with a lock on it?

[image: The lock on a side angle]

[image: Lock without cover]

[image: Lock with screws and plate removed]

Comment: I sure hope you are getting the landlord to foot the bill on this project.  Don't forget to include your labor.

Comment: Nope!  They want to charge me to install one, thus me posting here so I can do it myself for free (minus the cost of the lock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick trip to Home Depot or Loewes will find you a selection of similar door knobs with locks that should fit into exactly the same fitting.

You'll find either the ones that lock when you're inside, just pressing the button, or ones that take a key in the centre of the handle.

It should be a simple matter of unscrewing and removing both handles, and sliding the new handles in place through the existing bolt mechanism.

I've replaced a bunch of door handles that way, both locking and not.

Something like this: [Locking door handle](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=202099346&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&MERCH=REC-_-product-2-_-202099345-_-202099346-_-N&locStoreNum=980), and only $15.

Comment: Is this a standard door knob then?  Or is it a larger size/different mount?

Comment: I would take it down to a HomeDepot/Lowes, and see what fits in the same size. As for the mount, normally they inner bolt has a semi-circular opening for the handle's hasp to slide through.